# Deleting in a linked list having many occurences of a value

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

1. I am using this piece of code to delete a specific value from my linked list but when I create a linked list having many occurrences of a value. And if a try to delete that value it goes in infinite loop.
2. But when a create a linked list with distinct values than it works fine. What should I do?

My code,

```
struct link** delete(int value, struct link** head)
{
    struct link* temp=*head;
    struct link* q;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
    }
    else{
        while(temp->data!=value){
            q=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        q->next=temp->next;
        temp->next=NULL;
        free(temp);
        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but you check that `head` is not `NULL` *after* you dereference `head`.

Comment: My previous comment is a case of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and you also have that in the loop. What if `temp` is `NULL`? It *should* be `NULL` sooner or later in the loop, unless you don't initialize the `next` pointer properly. And here you have a hint about what could be wrong.

Comment: Do you want **all** of the specific value occurrences removed, or just the *first*? There is a significant difference in the algorithm.

Comment: shoud be `return NULL if(head==NULL)`

Comment: we still don't know whether OP wants to delete all occurences of given value or just a first

Comment: just the first value of occurences

Comment: @user3283576 ok. updated answer for a shorter version if you only want to delete the first value. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm has numerous problems. Including, but not limited to...

- Dereference `temp` without checking for NULL. Undefined behavior if you're at the end of the list and `temp` falls to NULL.
- There is no return value if the initial list pointer is NULL.
- Dereferencing `head` before checking it for NULL.

And others, but...

Use the head pointer-to-pointer to your advantage to walk the list by address-of-**links**. And done properly, there is no need to return a node pointer. The head of the list will properly update as-needed even if a victim value happens to occupy the first node in the list. The following code will remove *all* elements in a list that match a specific value. It can be made considerably more efficient if the list is known-sorted, but for now:

```
void delete(int value, struct link** head)
{
    if (!head)
    {
        printf("error");
        return;
    }

    while (*head)
    {
        if ((*head)->data == value)
        {
            struct link *tmp = *head;
            *head = tmp->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
        else
        {
            head = &(*head)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. The most important part of the above code is to NOT advance the pointer-to-pointer `head` to the next link in the chain if the value is being removed. Instead, it joins the next value where the current node (the one about to be deleted) resides. Once done, the target node is "orphaned" and you can safely delete it. `*head` automatically references the next node to test.

---

**Edit: Update for single-item-removal-only** (saw in general-comment)

```
void delete_one(int value, struct link** head)
{
    if (!head)
    {
        printf("error");
        return;
    }

    while (*head && (*head)->data != value)
        head = &(*head)->next;

    if (*head)
    {
        struct link *tmp = *head;
        *head = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

The function contains many errors and has undefined behaviour. For example it returns nothing in case when head is equual to NULL. or variable q will be unintialized in case when the first node contains the value.

I would write the function the following way

```
int delete( struct link **head, int value )
{
    int success = 0;
    if ( head == NULL ) return success;

    struct link *target = *head;
    struct link *prev = NULL;

    while ( target != NULL & target->data != value )
    {
        prev = target;
        target = target->next;
    }

    success = target != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( prev == NULL )
        {
            *head = target->next;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = target->next;
        }
        free( target );
    }    

   return success;
}
```